# Why Is My Function Alternating Between Working and Then Not Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

This is my very first ever question asked here, so I do apologise in advance if I am not following correct guidelines.

Basically what I'm trying to do is to manually code side-section navigating in Javascript. The navigating itself is working just fine, one can click either left or right and the sections will scroll left and right endlessly in a carousel. But when I try to set the previous pages `scrollTop` back to `0` once the user has moved off the section I run into problems.

If I scroll through each section and scroll a bit of the way down on each, when I return to the first page and cycle through them again, they seem to alternate as to whether their `scrollTop` was actually set to `0`.

HTML body:

```
<div class="Arrow" id="arrowLeft"></div>
<div class="Arrow" id="arrowRight"></div>
<section class="Page" id="page1"><div class="PageContent"></div></section>
<section class="Page" id="page2"><div class="PageContent"></div></section>
<section class="Page" id="page3"><div class="PageContent"></div></section>
<section class="Page" id="page4"><div class="PageContent"></div></section>
<section class="Page" id="page5"><div class="PageContent"></div></section>
<section class="Page" id="page6"><div class="PageContent"></div></section>
<section class="Page" id="page7"><div class="PageContent"></div></section>
<section class="Page" id="page8"><div class="PageContent"></div></section>
<script src="JavaScript/scroller.js"></script>
```

Javascript:

```
//initialising variables and populating arrays
var currentPage = 0;
var previousPage = 0;
var pages = document.getElementsByClassName("Page");
var sections = [];
for (i=0;i<pages.length;i++) {
    sections.push(pages[i]);
}
var pageOffSets = [0, 100, 200, 300, 400, -300, -200, -100];
var zOffSets = [0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-3,-2,-1];
for (i = 0;i<sections.length;i++) {
    sections[i].style.left = pageOffSets[i] + "vw";
    sections[i].style.zIndex = zOffSets[i];
}


//Navigate function
function slidePage(direction) {
        previousPage = currentPage;
    if (direction=="right") {
        currentPage+=1;
        if (currentPage>7) {
            currentPage = 0;
        }
        var hold = sections.shift();
        sections.push(hold);

         for (i=0;i<sections.length;i++) {
            sections[i].style.left = pageOffSets[i] + "vw";
            sections[i].style.zIndex = zOffSets[i];
        }
    }

    if (direction=="left") {
        currentPage-=1;
        if (currentPage<0) {
            currentPage = 7;
        }
        var hold = sections.pop();
        sections.unshift(hold);

         for (i=0;i<sections.length;i++) {
            sections[i].style.left = pageOffSets[i] + "vw";
            sections[i].style.zIndex = zOffSets[i];
        }
    }

    //!!!
    //This is the part that is supposed to set the scrollTop back to 0
    //!!!
    setTimeout(function(){
        sections[previousPage].scrollTop = 0;
    }, 1000);
}


//Event listeners for when the user clicks
document.getElementById("arrowLeft").addEventListener("click", function(){
    slidePage("left");
});
document.getElementById("arrowRight").addEventListener("click", function(){
    slidePage("right");
});
```

I would really appreciate if someone could point out what I'm doing wrong.

**Edit**:
Here is the CSS if you need it:

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

section {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
          transition-duration: 0.4s;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.Arrow {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  top: 48%;
}

.Arrow:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#arrowRight {
  right: 0;
}

#page1 {
  background-color: #c81996;
}

#page2 {
  background-color: #64324b;
}

#page3 {
  background-color: #1996c8;
}

#page4 {
  background-color: #324b64;
}

#page5 {
  background-color: #96c819;
}

#page6 {
  background-color: #4b6432;
}

#page7 {
  background-color: #f0fa1e;
}

#page8 {
  background-color: #fa1ef0;
}

.PageContent {
  height: 8000px;
  width: 90vw;
  margin: 5vw;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(red), to(yellow));
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
  position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. You are rotating the `sections` array inside your function, so the `previousPage` index is no longer correct once your anonymous function is fired.
2. The `previousPage` variable referenced when setting `scrollTop` after the timeout can change before the timeout elapses.

The simplest fix would be to rotate `pageOffSets` and `zOffSets` arrays instead:

```
if (direction == "right") {

    currentPage++;

    if (currentPage >= sections.length) {
        currentPage = 0;
    }

    // rotate pageOffsets    
    {
        var x = pageOffSets.pop();
        pageOffSets.unshift(x);
    }

    // rotate zOffsets
    {
        var x = zOffSets.pop();
        zOffSets.unshift(x);
    }

     for (i=0;i<sections.length;i++) {
        sections[i].style.left = pageOffSets[i] + "vw";
        sections[i].style.zIndex = zOffSets[i];
    }

} else {

    currentPage--;

    if (currentPage < 0) {
        currentPage = sections.length - 1;
    }

    // rotate pageOffsets    
    {
        var x = pageOffSets.shift();
        pageOffSets.push(x);
    }

    // rotate zOffSets    
    {
        var x = zOffSets.shift();
        zOffSets.push(x);
    }  

     for (i=0;i<sections.length;i++) {
        sections[i].style.left = pageOffSets[i] + "vw";
        sections[i].style.zIndex = zOffSets[i];
    }
}
```

And you need to capture a copy of the `previousPage` variable:

```
// capture a copy of the index so that it doesn't change
var prev = previousPage;

setTimeout(function() {
    sections[prev].scrollTop = 0;
}, 500);
```